# Python remove sections of string based on fluid start/end point

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace

I am using a pandas data frame and would like a solution to the below if possible please.

I have string 'A' and would like to amend it to remove certain sections shown in string 'B' of it based on identifying a start and end point (The data contains many rows and the items removed can appear anywhere within the string)

A -

```
Sunshine <long swing-people="11-22-33">#Drive</long>, A frog is any member of a diverse and largely   <long swing-people="11-22-33">#Thru</long> carnivorous group of short-bodied, tailless amphibians.
```

B -

```
Sunshine #Drive, A frog is any member of a diverse and largely #Thru carnivorous group of short-bodied, tailless amphibians.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but i cannot comment yet...

Are the starting/ending points already identified ?

In these examples it seems the starting point is `#` and the ending point a single `.`, is that always the case ?
if so this should work (cf pandas' [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)):

```
df[column_name].str.replace(r"#.*(?=\.)", "", regex=True)
```

edit: i (again) got mixed up between `str.replace` and `pandas.Series.str.replace`... fixed the code snippet